# How to get better anti-aliasing results in Cairo (examples shown)

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, antialiasing, cairo

Building a project using Cairo for graphics processing. Neither of the anti-aliasing options produce a good enough result. I'm using an ARGB32 surface and writing to png.

I have tried using all of the hinting styles but I can see no change in the result.

The best option for text on both white and black will be option 4 but as you can see, it's still not as nice as an output produced from the imagemagick library in example 5.

Any input or suggestions welcome.

**1. Using 'ANTIALIAS_DEFAULT'**

[image: example 1]

**2. Using 'ANTIALIAS_NONE'**

[image: example 2]

**3. Using 'ANTIALIAS_GRAY'**

[image: example 3]

**4. Using 'ANTIALIAS_SUBPIXEL'**

[image: axample 4]

**5. Using Imagemagick and it's default anti-aliasing**

[image: example 5]

Comment: Can I ask why Cairo, if the imagemagick library is the best tool why switch?  Are you just gaining experience with Cairo?  Curious...

Comment: Cairo is much quicker in processing images, especially when there are multiple layers to process. It also aided my PDF requirements more suitably.

Answer (score 6):

If you are stuck with Cairo, a workaround would be manual supersampling.  Basically render it at a larger resolution (twice or 4 times the width and height), and then resize it to the correct size.